# send sms api to the html php form without goto location header

Tags: php, html, api, sms

html form for collecting data

```
<form method="post" action="test.php" name="f2" onSubmit="return contact_validate1(this)">
<ul>
<li>
<label>Name :</label>
<input name="name" type="text" required> 
</li>

<li>
<label>Email :</label>
<input name="email" type="email" required  placeholder="Enter Your Valid Email"> 
</li>
<li>
<label>Mobile :</label>
<input name="mobile" type="text" required pattern="[0-9]{10,}$" placeholder="Enter Your Mobile Number"> 
</li>

<li>
<input name="" class="submit" type="submit" value="">
</li>
</ul>
</form>
```

test.php //to get values

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
 $name=$_POST['name'];
 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $mobile = $_POST['mobile'];


$headers = "From: training@smeclabs.com  \nReply-To: ".$email."\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\nContent-Type:  text/html; charset=iso-8859-1";  
    $msg="<table><tr><td>Name: ".$name."</td></tr><tr><td>Email: ".$email."</td></tr><tr><td>Mobile Number: ".$mobile."</td></tr></table>";


/*  if($_SESSION["captcha"]==$_POST["captcha"])
{*/
    if(mail("training@myweb.com","Form Record Received",$msg,$headers))
    //$msg1="Email Sent Successfully";
    header( "Location:$location" );
    header("location:formsubmit.html");

?>
```

I want add an sms api to this form

eg:

```
http://smsad.smsapiindia.com/SendSms.aspx?username=xxx&password=xxx&to=$mobile&from=xxxx&message=Thank You for Contacting
```

without the header location
and show only the current header location formsubmit.html

Answer (score 0):

Use [**`cURL`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to submit data..

```
$url="http://smsad.smsapiindia.com/SendSms.aspx?username=xxx&password=xxx&to=$mobile&from=xxxx&message=Thanks";
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
$auth = curl_exec($curl);
if($auth)
{ 
if(mail("training@myweb.com","Form Record Received",$msg,$headers))
header( "Location:$location" ); //Some "success.php"
exit;
//header("location:formsubmit.html");
}
}
```

Comment: cURL support  enabled cURL Information 7.24.0 this shows my phpinfo file but the sms not getting and not forward to the url header, please help whre i put my code

Comment: $msg="xxx
I put after this code

$url="http://smsad.smsapiindia.com/SendSms.aspx?username=xxx&password=xxx&to=$mobile&from=xxxx&message=Thanks";
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
$auth = curl_exec($curl);
if($auth)
{ 
if(mail("training@myweb.com","Form Record Received",$msg,$headers))
header( "Location:$location" ); //Some "success.php"
exit;
//header("location:formsubmit.html");
}
}

?>
shows me bad request